# The canonical forcing of the GCH and direct limits.  

Tags: set-theory, forcing, gch

The motivation for this question is that I am working through an exercise to force the GCH (generalized continuum hypothesis) over a model of ZFC and obtain a model of ZFC where GCH holds.

The forcing is an ORD length iteration of $Add(\gamma^+, 1)$ at every cardinal $\gamma$ ($\gamma$ is a cardinal in $V^{P_{\gamma}})$, with Easton support.  I'll just say here what Easton support is:

1) at regular $\gamma$, $P_{\gamma}$ is the direct limit of $P_{\alpha}$, $\alpha < \gamma$, meaning that for all $p \in P_{\gamma}$ there is a $\beta < \gamma$ such that $p\restriction \beta \in P_{\beta}$ and for all $\xi \ge \beta$, $p(\xi) = 1$

2) otherwise, $P_{\gamma}$ is an inverse limit, meaning for all $p \in P_{\gamma}$, the restriction of $p$ to any smaller cardinal is in that stage of the forcing, and there is no imposition that the coordinates of $p$ be trivial past some smaller stage.

Note that at successor cardinals $\gamma$, $P_{\gamma}$ is automatically a direct limit if we force at cardinal stages.

My question is about forcing at singular cardinal stages.  These mathoverflow questions, answers, and the surrounding comments ([what goes wrong](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112736/what-goes-wrong-in-easton-forcing-if-we-dont-just-use-regular-cardinals), [definition of easton product](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116564/ill-admit-it-i-dont-understand-the-definition-of-the-easton-product)), were very helpful to me, but I still have a confusion.

Let me first explain what I do understand regarding forcing the GCH at singular cardinals and then my question.

Since $\gamma^+$ is regular for all $\gamma$, the important arguments to show that when we factor $P \cong P^{\le \gamma}*P^{> \gamma}$, the first factor satisfies the $\gamma^+$-chain condition and the second is $<\gamma^+$-closed, all go through, whether $\gamma$ is regular or singlular.

However, part of the above claim rests on a $\Delta$-system argument to show that $P^{\le \gamma}$ satisfies the $\gamma^+$-chain condition.  And it is here where we use that any condition $p \in P^{\le \gamma}$ has a small domain compared to $\gamma^+$, and so a $\gamma^+$ sized set of domains of conditions in $P^{\le \gamma}$ forms a $\Delta$-system.

What can I say in the case of singular cardinals?  How can the $\gamma^+$ sized set of domains of conditions in $P^{\le \gamma}$ form a $\Delta$-system if we used an inverse limit to support the iteration at that stage?  Why not impose a direct limit at every stage of forcing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me take the case of $\aleph_\omega$ as a specific example. Similar considerations apply at other singulars.

If you want $\sigma$-closure above $\omega_1$, you need the full support at $\aleph_\omega$; bounded  support (i.e., direct limit) will not be closed enough.

Also: You need not worry about collapsing $\aleph_\omega$ (or changing its cofinality). If the elements of an unbounded set of cardinals below $\aleph_\omega$ stay cardinals, then $\aleph_\omega$ will stay a cardinal as well (and if a cobounded set of cardinals below $\aleph_\omega$ is collapsed to $\lambda$, then $\aleph_\omega$ will certainly not become $\lambda^+$ in the extension, and hence collapse as well.  If $\kappa$ is a singular cardinal of cofinality $\lambda < \kappa$, then the cofinality of $\kappa$ will only change if the cofinality of $\lambda$ changes.  This will be true no matter what support you take.

Comment: I'm starting to get the idea, but I don't understand fully.  What you mean by the $\sigma$-closure above $\omega_1$ (that the second p.o. of the factoring at $\omega_1$ is $\omega_1$-closed?) and why we need full support at $\aleph_{\omega}$ to ensure this?  

Comment: Yes, I mean $<\omega_1$-closure in the second factor at $\omega_1$.  We need full support because otherwise we could construct a decreasing $\omega$-sequence of conditions $(p_n)$, where $p_n$ has support bounded by $\aleph_n$, which will not have a limit. 

Comment: Thanks.  I see why we need full support at $\aleph_{\omega}$ in order to have a limit point for the sequence you described above, and see how to generalize to all singular cardinals.  And, your last paragraph answers why we don't even need a $\Delta$-system argument on a singular cardinal for the proof since preserving regular cardinals (and applying a $\Delta$-system argument there) will ensure this.  And, in the part of the proof where we show $Add(\lambda, 1)$ forces $2^{\lambda} = \lambda^+$ at stage $\lambda$, we only need closure on the later stages.